# Vuex migrating a state property to another type under a feature flag

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuex

I have an auth vuex store
It has a Cognito user

```
export interface AuthState {
  user: CognitoUser
}
```

However, I'm trying to migrate the user to be a custom user

```
export interface User {
  username: string
  country: string
  language: string
  phone_number: string
}
```

How can I do this efficiently under a feature flag?

I would greatly appreciate an article explaining the basics of how to build vue code in such a manner so this is easier in the future

Also, there are some issues such as CognitoUser implementing a getUsername Method but my User interface does not, how can I solve this? (CognitoUser implements far more methods that I would like to create for the interface, is there a way to check if the user is either cognito or an instance of my user interface and under an if do certain things)

I was thinking on something like this (but it does not work)

```
export function getUsername(user: CognitoUser | User ): string {
  if (user == CognitoUser) {
    return user.getUsername()
  }

  return user.Username
}
```

I'm using Vue, and typescript
Thanks!

Comment: The question lacks the essential parts. What is CognitoUser exactly? TS types don't exist at runtime so it's up to the implementation if you can detect it with duck typing or else